# Tensorflow error when using Custom Loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is the error message i get :

> assertion failed: [10 250 250] [11]    [[node
> ssim_loss/SSIM/Assert_2/Assert (defined at
> D:\Documents\neural_network\image_upscaler\nn2.py:33) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_7302]
>
> Function call stack: train_function

Here's my code

```
def ssim_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, 2.0))

def relu_bn(inputs):
    relu = ReLU()(inputs)
    bn = BatchNormalization()(relu)
    return bn


def build_model_shi(upscale_factor=2, channels=1):
    conv_args = {
        "activation": "relu",
        "kernel_initializer": "Orthogonal",
        "padding": "same",
    }
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, None, channels))
    x = layers.Conv2D(128, 5, **conv_args)(inputs)
    x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, **conv_args)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, **conv_args)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(channels * (upscale_factor ** 2), 3, **conv_args)(x)
    outputs = tf.nn.depth_to_space(x, upscale_factor)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    #loss_fn = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    loss_fn = ssim_loss
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_fn,)
    return model
    

def load_data(PATH):
    start = time()
    xte = np.load(PATH + "xtef.npy")
    print("xte loaded")
    xtr = np.load(PATH + "xtrf.npy")
    print("xtr loaded")
    ytr = np.load(PATH + "ytrf.npy")
    print("ytr loaded")
    yte = np.load(PATH + "ytef.npy")
    print("yte loaded")
    end = time()
    print("loaded in",end - start,"seconds")
    xtr = np.array(xtr,"float16")
    ytr = np.array(ytr,"float16")
    xte = np.array(xte,"float16")
    yte = np.array(yte,"float16")
    return xtr,xte,ytr,yte
    '''print("loading dataset")
    X = np.load(PATH + "X.npy")
    Y = np.load(PATH + "Y.npy")
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.05, random_state=42)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test'''

def train(PATH,BATCH_SIZE,EPOCHS):
    xtr, xte, ytr, yte = load_data(PATH)
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(PATH + "model.hdf5", monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max') #checkpointing it
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint,EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, min_delta=0.0001)]
    model = build_model_shi()
    history = model.fit(xtr, ytr, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,validation_data=(xte,yte),callbacks=callbacks_list)  #train time
    results = model.predict(xte)
    np.save(PATH + "model_op",results)
    np.save(PATH + "model_ip",xte)
    np.save(PATH + "model_gt",yte)
    del xtr, xte, ytr, yte

train(PATH,BATCH_SIZE,EPOCHS)
```

The model works just fine when i use MSE as my loss function. But i t gives me this error when i use my own "ssim_loss" as my loss function.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Turns out the shapes of the tensors passed to the ssim function needed reshaping.

```
def ssim_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred,[-1,250,250,1])
    y_true = tf.reshape(y_true,[-1,250,250,1])
    return 1 - tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred,max_val = 255))
```

in my case the image size is 250x250x1